# Why 'Enthalpy change' (Delta H) is equal to 'Heat transfer at constant pressure' (Qp)?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy, heat

Why 'Enthalpy change' (∆H) is equal to 'Heat transfer at constant pressure' (Qp)?

∆H = ∆U + ∆pV, here only expansion work done by the sustem is added. If non expansion work is done on the system then it should be,
∆H ≠ Qp.
What's wrong? Explain.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73098/discussion-on-question-by-tontyton-why-enthalpy-change-delta-h-is-equal-to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enthalpy is a intensive property of the material that has nothing to do with the specific process that the material is subjected to.
It just so happens in a constant pressure condition, involving only P-V work, that the change in enthalpy is equal to the heat added.

If non expansion work is done on the system, then ∆H≠Qp. It should be mentioned while writing '∆H = ∆U + p∆V =Qp', that 'it is applicable when only p-V work is done'.

Thanks to @ChesterMiller

Comment: Why are they equal? $$dH=TdS + VdP$$ but $dQ_{rev}=TdS$. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In,Thermodynamics,Work is defined as 
$W$= $-\int_{V_1}^{V_2}pdV$. So, if $dV$=0, there is no work done on the system,as $V_1=V_2$.

Coming to the enthalpy,you are right.
$\Delta$H=$\Delta$U + $\Delta$($PV$).But if you apply the product rule then,
$\Delta$H=$\Delta$U + $P$$\Delta$V + $V$$\Delta$P.
At, constanst presurre,$\Delta$P=$0$. so at constant pressure,$\Delta$H=$\Delta$U + $P$$\Delta$V.
But,according,to first law of Thermodynamics,
$Q$= $\Delta$U - $W$.At,constant pressure, the $p$ in the integral comes out.So,
$W$= $-p\int_{V_1}^{V_2}dV$= -$p$($V_2-V_1$) = -$p$$\Delta$V.So, first law in constant presuure becomes,
$Q_p$= $\Delta$U - (-$p$$\Delta$V)= $\Delta$U+$p$$\Delta$V= $\Delta$H. Thus, it is justified why Enthalpy change equals Heat change at constant pressure.

Comment: Your formatting is terrible. Use correct punctuation and check out https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/should-we-correct-math-formatting